# Operations on characters in data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

My data frame (file_df) looks like:

```
Filename
A_2005.txt
A_2006.txt
B_2007.txt
```

I want to do:

```
Filename Station_Year Station Year
A_2005.txt A_2005 A 2005
A_2006.txt A_2006 A 2006
B_2007.txt B_2007 B 2007
```

I tried:

```
file_df$Station_Year  <- strsplit(file_df$Filename,"[.]")[[1]][1]
file_df$Station       <- strsplit(file_df$Filename,"[._]")[[1]][1]
file_df$Year          <- strsplit(file_df$Filename,"[._]")[[1]][2]
```

but I get:

```
Filename Station_Year Station Year
A_2005.txt A_2005 A 2005
A_2006.txt A_2005 A 2005
B_2007.txt A_2005 A 2005
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two approaches:

**1) sub**

```
# test data
DF <- data.frame(Filename = c("A_2005.txt", "A_2006.txt", "B_2007.txt"))

transform(DF, Station_Year = sub("\\..*", "", Filename),
              Station = sub("_.*", "", Filename),
              Year = as.numeric(sub(".*_(.*)\\..*", "\\1", Filename)))
```

giving:

```
    Filename Station_Year Station Year
1 A_2005.txt       A_2005       A 2005
2 A_2006.txt       A_2006       A 2006
3 B_2007.txt       B_2007       B 2007
```

**2) strsplit**

```
s <- do.call("rbind", strsplit(as.character(DF$Filename), "[_.]"))
cbind(DF, data.frame(Station_Year = paste(s[, 1], s[, 2], sep = "_"), 
                     Station = s[, 1], 
                     Year = as.numeric(s[, 2])))
```

*ADDED* Second solution. Minor improvements.

Answer (score 0):

If all the filenames are the same length you could use substr:

```
file_df$Station_Year <- substr(file_df$Filename, 1,6)
file_df$STATION <- substr(file_df$Filename, 1,1)
file_df$YEAR <- substr(file_df$Filename, 3,6)
```

But that would only work if the filenames are all always the same length.

Answer (score 0):

This will not get you the result you want.  @g-grothendieck's post is the one you want.

The issue that you are having with your method is that `strsplit()` returns a list with each element representing the result from reach element of `file_df$Filename`.

```
strsplit(file_df$Filename,"[.]")
#[[1]]
#[1] "A_2005" "txt"   

#[[2]]
#[1] "A_2006" "txt"   

#[[3]]
#[1] "B_2007" "txt"
```

In your code, you only ever select the first element of the resulting list (the `[[1]]`) which causes your result to repeat the values you want from the first filename.